# How to redirect to another page in Laravel 8 immediately after authorization?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In `RouteServiceProvider` wrote `public const HOME = '/ welcome';` But directs here only if the user is not authenticated. And I need to send here right after registration or authorization (now redirects to the root directory "/".

Comment: Read some documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: Which laravel version ?

Comment: @OmerYILMAZ Laravel 8X

Comment: @N69S I read documentation, but it not work

Comment: yeah, that's for older version of laravel. Add the code of your authenticating controller to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your LoginController (if you are using laravel authentification package) you can set the attribute `$redirectTo` as the destination.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
//...
}
```

It is fairly commented and self explanatory by default on installation.

Comment: Thanks, but I make another. public function authenticated()
    {
        if(Auth::id())
        {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return redirect()->route('welcome');
    }

Comment: protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard'; I make this, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use MiddleWare to check if the user registered or even already loggedin
this is one example :

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Session()->has('loginId') && (url('login')==$request->url()|| url('registration')
    ==$request->url())){
        return back();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```